# Acer spin 5 [ubuntu 18.04 freezes when copying files or compiling a code]

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, acer

Recently I bought an Acer spin 5 Intel-i7 8th gen laptop with 8gb of RAM and 512gb sdd along with Intel integrated graphics.

It came with Windows 10 but I wanted to use Ubuntu, so I made it dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04. On Ubuntu 18.04, every time I copy something or compile a small code it freezes. Please help me out if somebody has any solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you ssh to the machine (if the daemon is installed) while it is frozen?

Comment: Hi Andersen, Thanks for the replay. when the machine is frozen i can't even use ssh on that.

Comment: I have also tried the solutions given on this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/397249/system-freezes-unresponsive-unusable-when-copying-large-file-to-usb but no success.

Comment: Did you do _anything_ else than suggested by the installer while installing?  Does it run on the live media?

Comment: No, I didn't do anything. And yes it runs on live media.

Comment: I would suggest you ask on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Are your running an NVMe SSD? And have you tried Ubuntu 19.10? It comes with a newer kernel which might solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Imoly, I haven't  tried 19.04  as some of the codes and packages that I am using are not compatible with 19.04. anyway, thanks for the suggestions.